# Changing attributes of multiple variables in data frame

Tags: r, purrr

I want to change the labels of variables in a data frame. I do not want to use packages like Hmisc but want to simply use tools provided in the tidyverse. I think I nearly made it, but I got stuck. Here is a working example:

```
    library(tidyverse)
    DF = data.frame(a=1:2,b=3:4) 
    attr(DF$a, "label") <- "Old label a"
    attr(DF$b, "label") <- "Old label b"

    new_labels <- c("First label", "Second label")

    replace_labels <- function(df,new_labels){
        column_names <- colnames(df)
        purrr::map2(column_names, new_labels, ~ (df[[.x]] <-`attr<-`(df[[.x]], "label", .y)))
    }
```

Now when applying the function to the dataframe

```
replace_labels(DF, new_labels)
```

I get a list instead of a dataframe, which is not the desired output and converting the list back to a dataframe by transforming does not seem to be the right approach and if I do it with `bind_cols()` all attributes are lost again. Any improvement to the function is welcome!

Comment: why not use `base r`? `colnames(DF)<-new_labels`. This works with `tibbles` as well. Simple and self-explanatory IMO. Why use `tidyverse`?! Only reason I heard of so far was compability

Comment: Thank you! I thought about this,  but as far as I understood `colnames()` changes the column names and not the attributes of a variable. I like to have a flexible solution that allows me in a convenient way to change attributes of a variable within a dataframe, in order to deal with long variable descriptions rather than the short names.

Comment: It should be the same as long as you stay within `R`. I guess that, if you use some tool which transforms code or dataframes, translating the `base r`-logic does not really work. But tbh I have never done any of this, therefore I try to stick with `base r`, wherever I can :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do `DF[] <- replace_labels(DF, new_labels)` at the end so DF is still a dataframe.

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly

Comment: Your welcome. You might consider to accept or upvote the answer if it was helpful to you. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I accepted the answer, no public upvoting possible for me as I have too little reputation (yet) :-)